# Do I really need a reverse proxy for my vps setup

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, vps

I want to understand if I really need a reverse proxy for my vps setup? I am a complete noob at server configuration and all I want is to make my websites as secure as a noob can make them.

I want to host 3 independent websites using server blocks in nginx and I already understand how to do it, it's the reverse proxy thing I don't get!

site1.com

site2.com

site3.com

Comment: Since you deleted the same Question without clarification. To host different Website on the same host, No you dont. Except if you want to use Docker or LXC Container

Comment: A reverse proxy server is a type of proxy server that typically sits behind the firewall in a private network and directs client requests to the appropriate backend server. So if you have multiple machines you probably need a reverse proxy in a single server scenario it's a nice to have. A secure web server doesn't come from a reverse proxy but minimizing the so-called surface of attack.

Comment: @Ace but only in case the Reverse-Proxy is not the same host where the sites will be hosted.

Comment: Well i delete the former question because it was badly formulated and all the answers i was getting seem to assume i was a pro and it was not the case.

Comment: @Ace i don't have multiple machines, just a single vps server where i want to host my 3 websites and make them as secure as i can with my limited knowledge. I was OK setting up nginx, installing lemp stack and configuring http on server block until the reverse proxy ruined my last 3 days. I will also setup ssl to get https running.

Comment: As I already asked in your first question, please provide more information about your configuration. How is/are your server(s) configured to server these websites? Are they on only one host or on multiple hosts, are you using containers, are you using application servers, are they just PHP scripts that are residing in different folders on the same host .... you need to provide more context.

Comment: If you don't reveal some portion of your nginx config file, this question does not have the right context. What is the "reverse proxy" part that you are talking about?

Comment: @ Gerald Schneider, Hi Gerald and thank for laying a hand, i am under ubuntu 20.04 on a vps and i made server block for each of the 3 websites. I am using only nginx as a server without docker and i don't have any app just 2 mybb site and one static website for my game.

Comment: @Lex Li  Hi lex thank for replying, my goal was to put all 3 websites behind a proxy and pointing to my vps ip address who would be as a fake server with only the nginx welcome page but maybe i am wrong about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Basic Website Hosting

### Solution 1: With HTTP to HTTPS redirect

- Both server_name must match the same
- Recommended way to do so.
- Remind, that the default return would be 302, check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection) what would be the best in your case

```
server {
        server_name example.com;
        listen 80;
        return 307 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name exmaple.com;
                location / {
                root /var/www/vhosts/example.com;
}

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

### Solution 2: Basic HTTP Hosting

- not recommend anymore, due to HTTPS is preferred by default on the Browsers.

```
server {
        server_name example.com;
        listen 80;
                location / {
                root /var/www/vhosts/example.com;
}
}
```

- These Steps have to repeated for each site.
- On Debian: use /etc/nginx/sites-enabled and therefore each domain a separate file for easier administration.

The Question has been ansered based on the Rare Information given.

Comment: Thank for the answer but i was already familiar with server block since it was working before i tried to mess with the reverse proxy thing. So if i use my server block with https/ssl is this enough for my websites to be reasonably secure? I didn't want to go for docker since i found this to be over the top for hosting 3 simple websites.

Comment: the reverse proxy does not increase the security. It all depends on the site itself and which software is used. Security comes mostly from a Trust-Zero Principle, Strong Passwords, currently updated Software. But if someone is against you, the Person will find a way to harm you in any ways. the Only Thing you want to use it, is for LXC Containers, due you could update one website, without affecting others.

Comment: Thank for your patience and help i truly appreciate so if i recap my situation being already under ssh tunneling + https/ssl with only port 80,443 and 8888 to replace port 22 i should be at least reasonably secure correct?

Comment: replacing the default ports does not increase the security

Comment: I know it is not more secure but i read in a few place that there was less attacks from script kiddie!

Comment: the Skript kiddies does even not care if it's a reverse proxy or not. This is the same for nginx. it forward the Request as it is. What you looking for is  a WAF. But it has to be used and configured wisely.